# Android Profiling : what are FinalizerDaemon, FinalizerWatchDogDaemon,ReferenceQueueDaemon,Different binders and JDWP?

Tags: android, performance-testing, android-memory

I am implementing one library for Applications. Traceview after application is using the library looks like :
[image]

If I am not using the library, Only main thread is shown in the traceview. So what are these different Daemons,JDWP and Binders and when these are started by Android OS ?

Comment: "So what are these different Daemons" -- they are part of the garbage collection and finalizer system, AFAIK. "JDWP" -- that is your debugger. "and Binders" -- they are threads for processing incoming IPC events. "when these are started by Android OS ?" -- the JDWP thread presumably is created as part of debugging your app. The rest should be forked as part of starting up your process.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks a lot. But why these daemons are started only if i am using my library ? if I am using only the sample application, these are not starting. GC should start atleast once or my library is creating too much objects that is starting the GC ?

Comment: "But why these daemons are started only if i am using my library ?" -- beats me. I see them all the time.

Comment: @CommonsWare : if you are seeing them on ur app...then I think it is ok :)

Comment: Actually, I should clarify that comment. I rarely visit the screen you cite, in part because AFAIK that is Eclipse, and I haven't used Eclipse for much in ~2 years. However, when I do poke around at seeing what threads are running, I commonly see those daemon threads.

Comment: I am using Monitor tool of Android Studio. I think this is same on both studio and eclipse

Comment: Ah, right, I keep forgetting that is there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

FinalizerDaemon is used to abort if any finaliser is running longer.

FinalizerWatchdog is watch dog service for finaliser daemon.

JDWP is java debugger service.

ReferenceQueueDaemon is  heap management thread moves elements from the garbage collector's pending list to the managed reference queue.

Not sure about binders.

More details at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/java/lang/Daemons.java